# How to distinguish bound method or a function from a class?

Tags: python

`type(product.get_datasheet)` shows:

```
<bound method product.get_datasheet of <pkg.product object at 0x7fbb6c09c290>>
```

I need to distinguish `product.get_datasheet` from a(ny) class. `callable` does not help since per `callable`'s docstring:

```
Note that classes are callable, as are instances with a __call__() method.
```

I'm writing something like data binding, and I need bound method called in a template, while if it's a class it should not be called.

How can I distinguish from a function or a bound method (but not class method!) from a class?

Comment: You forgot the case of callable instances (instances of a class implementing `__call__`)

Comment: Else you may want to have a look at the `types` module...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a general class like:

```
>>> class A:
...   def __call__(self): pass
...
```

And the types module:

```
>>> import types
```

You can test whether an object is a function (`callable` returns `True` for all tested object below):

```
>>> isinstance(A, (types.FunctionType, types.BuiltinFunctionType))
False
>>> isinstance(a, (types.FunctionType, types.BuiltinFunctionType))
False
>>> isinstance(A.__call__, (types.FunctionType, types.BuiltinFunctionType))
True
>>> isinstance(a.__call__, (types.FunctionType, types.BuiltinFunctionType))
False
```

And you can test whether an object is a method:

```
>>> isinstance(A, (types.MethodType, types.BuiltinMethodType))
False
>>> isinstance(a, (types.MethodType, types.BuiltinMethodType))
False
>>> isinstance(A.__call__, (types.MethodType, types.BuiltinMethodType))
False
>>> isinstance(a.__call__, (types.MethodType, types.BuiltinMethodType))
True
```

So, if you want to test whether an object `obj` is a:

- Function:

  - `isinstance(obj, (types.FunctionType, types.BuiltinFunctionType))` is `True`
- Method:

  - `isinstance(obj, (types.MethodType, types.BuiltinMethodType))` is `True`
- Function or method:

  - `isinstance(obj, (types.FunctionType, types.BuiltinFunctionType, types.MethodType, types.BuiltinMethodType))` is `True`
- Other callable object:

  - `isinstance(obj, (types.FunctionType, types.BuiltinFunctionType, types.MethodType, types.BuiltinMethodType))` is `False`
  - Therefore `not isinstance(obj, (types.FunctionType, types.BuiltinFunctionType, types.MethodType, types.BuiltinMethodType))` is `True`